# Finding the maximum from a array and what is runtime error in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

> Given N numbers, find the one that is of the highest value and print it.
> **Input**
> The first line of the input will contain N (0 < N < 1000<N<100).
> The following line will contain N integers, each between 11 and 10001000.
> **Output** 
> Print the maximum.

---

my ans was:

```
class program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] Numbers = new int[N];
        int Le = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
        }
        //int m = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Array.Sort(Numbers);
            
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Numbers[Numbers.Length-1]);
        

    }
}
```

}

But it was showing me about runtime error.

Can anyone tell me the right ans of the code and what is run time error?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the bug can't be reproduced and the code you provided seems to work fine. Please try to better explain your issue, your dev env and the data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: "Something about a runtime error". Programming is all about details and semantics. You'll have to learn to pay much more attention to those error messages if you want to be successful.

Comment: It would be great if you could post the runtime error message here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```
int m = Numbers[0];
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
    m = Numbers[i] > m ? Numbers[i] : m;
}
Console.WriteLine(m);
```

or this:

```
int m = Numbers[0];
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
    int n = Numbers[i];
    if (n > m)
        m = n;
}
Console.WriteLine(m);
```

No sorting required.

You code ran fine, however, without error for me.